# Using ScalaCheck with PeekPokeTester

Tags: chisel

Here is chisel3 test that uses ScalaCheck to perform property checking on a simple combinational circuit.

```
package stackoverflow

import org.scalatest.{ Matchers, FlatSpec, GivenWhenThen}
import org.scalacheck.{ Properties, Gen, Arbitrary}
import org.scalacheck.Prop.{ forAll, AnyOperators, collect}

import chisel3._
import firrtl_interpreter.InterpretiveTester

object G {
  val width = 8
}

class Add extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(G.width.W))
    val b = Input(UInt(G.width.W))
    val o = Output(UInt(G.width.W))
  })
  io.o := io.a + io.b
}

class AddTester {
  val s = chisel3.Driver.emit( () => new Add)
  val tester = new InterpretiveTester( s)
  def run( a : Int, b : Int) = {
    val result = (a + b) & ((1 << G.width)-1)
    tester.poke( s"io_a", a)
    tester.poke( s"io_b", b)
    tester.peek( s"io_o") ?= result
  }
}

object AddTest extends Properties("Add") {
  val t = new AddTester
  val gen = Gen.choose(0,(1 << G.width)-1)
  property("Add") = forAll( gen, gen) {
    case (a:Int,b:Int) => t.run( a, b)
  }
}
```

This uses the firrtl interpreter directly. Does anyone know how to do something similar using the PeekPokeTester so I can use the verilator and vcs backends as well?

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you have in mind? It's a lot more scalatesty in form. I haven't been able to get the gen stuff working here (there is some kind of weird interaction with chisel), and I'm more familiar with FreeSpec so I started with it. I also threw a printf and a println in so you could believe it was working.  This works with the interpreter backend as well.

```
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec
import org.scalacheck.Prop.AnyOperators
import chisel3._
import chisel3.iotesters.PeekPokeTester

class Add2 extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(G.width.W))
    val b = Input(UInt(G.width.W))
    val o = Output(UInt(G.width.W))
  })
  io.o := io.a + io.b
  printf("%d = %d + %d\n", io.o, io.a, io.b)
}

class ScalaTestyTester extends FreeSpec {
  "scalatest verilator test" in {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--backend-name", "verilator"), () => new Add2) { c =>
      new PeekPokeTester(c) {
        for(_ <- 0 until 10) {
          val a = BigInt(G.width, scala.util.Random)
          val b = BigInt(G.width, scala.util.Random)
          println(s"testing a = $a b = $b")
          val result = (a + b) & ((1 << G.width) - 1)
          poke(c.io.a, a)
          poke(c.io.b, b)
          step(1)
          peek(c.io.o) ?= result
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a scalacheck-style solution. My issue is that I can't derive the test class from both "Properties" (the scalacheck runner) and "PeekPokeTester". Delegation works with the firrtl interpreter. Is there a way to create an instance of a "PeekPokeTester" (or some other VCS-based tester) and then make peek/poke method calls on that instance?